# Obtain MYSQL column values as list in one variable

Tags: python, mysql

I want column values as list output to be

```
['Repair and Maintenance - General', 'Advance salary', 'EXIM Deposit', 'Office Cleaning Expenses']
```

but I'm able to obtain only this type of output

```
[('Repair and Maintenance - General',), ('Advance salary',), ('EXIM Deposit',), ('Office Cleaning Expenses',)]
```

with the following code, Can anyone please help me

```
import mysql
import mysql.connector
import pandas as pd


conn = mysql.connector.connect(host="localhost", user="root", 
passwd="Abcd11",database="entry",auth_plugin="mysql_native_password")
query= "select ledger from l_db_name"
cur=conn.cursor()
cur.execute(query)
rows=cur.fetchall()
conn.commit()

print(rows);
```

Answer (score 1):

extract the first element of each tuple with a list comprehension

```
rows = cur.fetchall()
rows = [row[0] for row in rows]
```